# Hide adjust last operator panel

Tags: panel

[image]

hello, I want to hide this Adjust Last Operator Panel.
Is it possible?

Many thanks

Comment: You can make it collapse by pressing that arrow next to "Move". It doesn't make it disappear but it gets relatively small you won't notice it anymore.

Comment: To disable it completely simply uncheck *View > Adjust last Operation*

Comment: @JachymMichal OMG How dare I see this now? Thank you very much!